# Nim lang syntax a = b = c = 7

Tags: nim-lang

How to solve error on syntax `var a = b = c = 7` being one RHS value for many LHS just like in C:

```
 int a,b,c ;
 a = b = c = 7 ;
```

so on Nim lang:

```
Error: invalid indentation
```

Help out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the earliest things in the [Tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#the-assignment-statement):

```
var a, b, c = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

xbello answered the question, but if we want to be similar at the C code, we should also answer how to do multiple affectations after declaration :

```
var a,b,c
(a,b,c) = (7,7,7)
```